# pyspark convert column in dataframe to datetime with no colons for time

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, databricks

I have a column in a dataframe that looks like "20221026 220032". I need to convert this to a datetime column but I don't have the colon separators for the time portion. I've attempted the following:

```
df_meta = df_meta.withColumn("filedatetime",F.to_timestamp(F.col("filedatetime_str"),"YYYYddmm HHmmss"))
```

But I get an error that it is an unrecognizable format. The reason my column comes this way is because is was parsed from a filename. Is there a way to convert this to a datetime without having to insert the colons?

Comment: there is a problem as you have twice the `mm` pattern. `m minute-of-hour` and `M/L month-of-year`. Check official [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) (It's java because spark uses JVM)

Comment: `MM` for months

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df_meta = df_meta.withColumn("filedatetime",F.to_timestamp(F.col("filedatetime_str"),"yMMdd HHmmss"))
```

spark date and time format can refer to [Datetime Patterns](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html)